# Disable Windows logo key + Ctrl + S keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, default-settings

can someone tell me how to disable <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> shortcut in Windows 10?

My OS:

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.17134 N/A Build 17134
```

This new shortcut came with the last feature update (Feature update to Windows 10 (consumer editions), version 1803, en-us)...

Thanks!

Comment: You may use `AutoHotkey` to execute some other command or program. It seems that Windows does not have feature of modifying or disabling a system shortcut.

Comment: it's possible to send another key press?

Comment: Using `AutoHotKey` you can disable/change most of windows default shortcut key actions. Refer [this](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Override.htm) for details.

Comment: I tried this way:
 ^#s::
 Send !+a
 Return but is not working

Comment: ok, I did it :)... AHK ftw :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with AutoHotKey:

```
^#s::
    Return
```

this is all you need to do.

if you want to do something with this combination, you can do it like this:

```
^#s::
    Send {Shift down}+{Alt down}+s+{Shift up}+{Alt up}
    Return
```