# Windows 10 shortcut disable - Win + Ctrl + S

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I was using ***<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>*** to launch one of my apps, but after last windows 10 update this is linked with some sound control wizard. It even can't start and launches this:

[image]

Is there any way to disable this using registry/gpedit/settings. Don't want to install some other app just to change one keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Though you already mentioned that you do not want to install any third party software. But [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1320726/disable-windows-logo-key-ctrl-s-keyboard-shortcut?noredirect=1#comment1968713_1320726) was successfully done using `AutoHotKey`. Just in case you change your mind.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of this solution, I did use AHK in previous versions of Windows, but I decided to minimize number of tools in toolchain. Otherwise I feel crippled on other peoples computers :) It would be very sad for Windows if this can't be done easy.

Comment: Any solutions? I have the same case only with Win+Ctrl+N and Narrator.

Comment: See [my question](https://superuser.com/questions/1527219/how-to-disable-winctrln-hotkey-that-opens-narrator-settings-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 2):

I successfully disabled this windows 10 shortcut using [this](https://www.top-password.com/blog/disable-specific-windows-key-shortcut/) guide.

**Notice**: using this method will disable ALL windows hotkeys that include the windows key and `s`. Unfortunately, as far as I know there's no way to disable a single hotkey combination.

Basically, open the registry editor, and just add a new registry key at this location:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced

name the new key `DisabledHotkeys` and give it the value `S`.

Reboot your system, and the hotkey will be disabled.

Obligatory warning: Don't touch the registry editor if you don't know what you're doing. It's for advanced users, and using it incorrectly can cause major issues. Use at your own risk.

Comment: Any idea how to disable exact shortcut, there are others with Win + S which are useful.

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I know, there's no option to disable only Win + shift + S. You can only disable all hotkeys that include `Win` and `S`. (unless you use a 3rd party tool like AHK, but I would really prefer a 1st party solution.)

Comment: Update: This solution isn't working for me at all today (the hotkey is no longer disabled, even though the key is still there... I even tried to delete, recreate, & reboot, but I can no longer disable the hotkey). Yesterday these steps did successfully disable the hotkey. So the implementation of this `DisabledHotkeys` registry key may be buggy, and only work occasionally. Curiously, it still works for disabling all the *other* win + s hotkeys, just not the one I actually want to disable (ctrl + win + s) :P