# How to disable Win+Ctrl+N hotkey that opens Narrator settings in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, narrator

It's easy enough to disable the main Narrator hotkey <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (in the very settings mentioned in the title), but **there seems to be no solution to disable**

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> that launches the settings dialog.

At least [this solution](https://www.ghacks.net/2015/03/22/how-to-disable-specific-global-hotkeys-in-windows/) doesn't work. And no answer has been supplied for [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1323118/windows-10-shortcut-disable-win-ctrl-s).

Am I really to change a well-memorized keyboard shortcut I used to have been using in VSCode under Windows 7, because... Windows. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Shortcut in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1325010/disable-shortcut-in-windows)

Comment: If you never need narrator in the future.... a quick and dirty way would be to delete Narrator.exe.

Comment: The problem is not with Narrator but with its settings dialog which is launched when you hit Win+Ctrl+N. Similarly if you hit Win+Ctrl+M you get Magnifier settings dialog (whatever Magnifier is). The point is that you get settings dialog and not the actual application itself. I couldn't care less for some Accessibility apps that M$ forces on people that don't ever use them and would gladly delete/rename them, if only that would solve anything.

Comment: I see. Sorry, I didn't fully read the question.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution, you might want to try.

> There are two programs that can help you to turn off specific Windows hotkeys, they are SharpKeys and AutoHotkey.
>
> SharpKeys allow you to turn off a specific hotkey or adjust it to another key as you want. Meanwhile, AutoHotKey will help you to turn off a specific hotkey by adding a script.
>
> Take a look at the following article:
>
> https://www.howtogeek.com/194811/how-to-prevent-the-windows-key-alttab-and-sticky-keys-from-ruining-your-gaming/

Comment: Using third-party software seems a bit extreme. Also, I didn't try it, but from the tone of the linked article it's more about all around disabling certain keys so they don't interfere with gaming. My case is different, **I want to use this hotkey**. Just not how Win10 forces mi to do, but like I did in Win7. Nevertheless, I appreciate you taking time to look for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There may a solution that need to add a new entry called DisableHotkey into the following registry:

> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced

Name the new string as “DisabledHotkeys“, and set its value as “N“, meaning to disable any keyboard shortcut that uses the combination of Win key and the disabled character in the String Value, such as Win+N, Win+Shift+N, etc.

The disadvantage of this way is that it will disable all hotkeys that use N letter.

Source: https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-disable-any-specific-win-keyboard-shortcut-in-windows

Comment: This is the solution I mentioned when I said "At least this solution doesn't work". Maybe it works for Win+N and Win+Shift+N, but it doesn't (at least for me) for Win+Ctrl+N.

Comment: @z33k - You really should edit your question to clarify that point instead of submitting a temporary comment.  You will receive much better answers by clarifying your question.